# To list droplet snapshots created on specific date with Respective IDs

Tags: api, digital-ocean, snapshot

i am having large number of droplet snapshots in Digital Ocean and i need to get the droplet snapshot ids created on specific date so i could use delete API to delete them.It would be great if some one could render their hand to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> **NOTE** Generally, you'll get (more) responses to questions if you show an attempt to solve the problem for yourself.

DigitalOcean's API is [well-documented](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/) and includes examples using `curl`, Golang and Ruby.

You have 3 problems to solve:

1. Query your account's Droplet Snapshots
2. Filter the results by a date
3. Verify that the list of Snapshots matches the ones that should be deleted
4. Delete the Droplet Snapshots that result.

###### Query your account's Droplet Snapshots:

https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/list_all_snapshots

As documented, for Droplets, use `/v2/snapshots?resource_type=droplet`

> **NOTE** It appears to not be possible to filter Snapshots by `created_at` datetime through the API directly.

Example provided by the documentation:

```sh
# List all Droplet snapshots
curl \
--request GET \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer ${DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN}" \
https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/snapshots?resource_type=droplet
```

> **NOTE** This will return the 1st page of at most 20 results. You will need to page through all results. See [Links & Pagination](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#section/Introduction/Links-and-Pagination)

###### Filter the results

Each page (!) of results is JSON with the following schema:

```
{
  "snapshots": [
    {
      "id": "",
      "name": "",
      "created_at": "2021-11-20T11:59:59Z",
      "regions": [],
      "resource_id": "",
      "resource_type": "",
      "min_disk_size": 0,
      "size_gigabytes": 0,
      "tags": []
    },
  ],
}
```

The `created_at` time is an RFC-3339 or ISO 8601 (!?) datetime. You'll need to decide what you want when you write "on a specific date".

You can use a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the JSON results to only include `id`'s that correspond to the appropriate `created_at` time.

You'll want to accumulate filtered results from each page (for the entire set of data). Let's assume this results in a bash array of `id` called `IDS`

###### Verify

Determine some verification to ensure that the list of IDs that you've captured matches the set that should be deleted.

###### Delete the filtered Droplet Snapshots

Once you're confident that the set of IDs matches those that you want to be (irrevocably) deleted...

https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/api/api-reference/#operation/delete_snapshot

Example provided by the documentation augmented to iterate over all `id`'s:

```sh
for ID in ${IDS[@]}
do
  curl \
  --request DELETE \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ${DIGITALOCEAN_TOKEN}" \
  https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/snapshots/${ID}
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts..I found a way to use a combination of bash and python to achieve the requitement.